# Unit testing functional interface

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, functional-interface

I have a public method like this:

```
public List<Resource> getResource(Function<InputStream, List<Resource>> funcToExecute)
{
    InputStream inp = getInputStream();
    return funcToExecute.apply(inp);
}
```

How do I unit test this functionality? How do I establish relation between inputstream and list of resource to be returned in my Unit tests?

Comment: Can you share what getInputStream() does?

Comment: getInputStream() returns a SequenceInputStream after combining inputstreams of multiple files that are read from server.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't too much logic here - just to make sure that the function is applied to your `InputStream`, so using something like `Mockito.verify` is probably the right way to go.

Unfortunately, `InputStream`s don't usually override `equals(Object)`, so you need some way around it. One possible option would be to `spy` your `getInputStream()` method:

```
@Test
public void testGetResource() {
    SomeClass someClass = Mockito.spy(new SomeClass());
    InputStream is = Mockito.mock(InputStream.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(is).when(someClass).getInputStream();

    Function<InputStream, List<Resource>> mockFunc = 
        Mockito.mock(Function.class);

    someClass.getResource(mockFunc);

    Mockito.verify(mockFunc).apply(someClass.getInputStream());
}
```